# Waking up async the Arduino while it's sleeping periodically

Tags: power, interrupt, arduino-pro-mini, sleep

I´m using `LowPower.h` and `PinChangeInt.h` libraries to put my Arduino into the sleep mode every 8 seconds and then it wakes up, modifies a counter and it goes to sleep again, but also I need to wake it up when a button is pressed asynchronously.

I´ve reached to wake up the Arduino every 8 seconds using `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF)` and, in other code, I´ve also reached to wake it up while it sleeps indefinitely with `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF)` but I can´t combine that periodical awakening with the asynchronous awakening.

Here is my code:

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Pines declaration

    loopsToSend = setTimeToSend();  //

    //The three async buttons 
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(4, readOpinion,RISING);
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(5, readOpinion,RISING);
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readOpinion,RISING);
}

void loop(){

    if(loops < loopsToSend ){

        byte opinionValue = readOpinion(); //This method must awake the Arduino ASYNC to give a value to the opinionValue var, write the result in the file and go to sleep 

        if(opinionValue != 0){
            Serial.println("Button pressed!");

            //Writing result in a file
            opiniones++;
            delay(500);
        }
        //Go to sleep 8 seconds
        LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
        opinionValue = 0;
    }
    else {
        wdt_disable();

        if(opiniones > 0){
            //Send file using GSM module
        }
        else{
            loops = 0;
        }
    }
    loops++;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Only the INT0 (pin2) and INT1 (pin3) pins can wake the arduino from SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN. So I don't know how the buttons could have worked in the first place. Are you sure the uC was really sleeping?

Comment: But I´m using the `PinChangeInt.h` to use any pin to generate the interrupt and it works.

Comment: @Gerben According to Nick Gammons [How do interrupts work on the Arduino Uno and similar boards?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/30969/23841) refference Q/A and the comments bellow, it woks (I've tested it). The External Interrupts in all modes and PinChange interrupts too.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/31659/17196

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
#include <PinChangeInterrupt.h>
#include <LowPower.h>

// I want to know when it was interrupted by PCINT:
volatile byte flag = 0;
void handler() {
    flag = 1;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachPCINT(digitalPinToPCINT(A0), handler, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("entering powerDown sleep mode");
  Serial.flush(); // wait for sending all data 

  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);

  if (flag == 1) {
    flag = 0;
    Serial.println("Pin change interrupt");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Timeout");
  }
}
```

However if you use RISING (or FALLING), it also wakes up from the sleep when pin changes back to the oposite state (and it'll be reported as Timeout).