# Waking up async the Arduino while it is sleeping periodically

Tags: interrupt, arduino-pro-mini

I´m using `LowPower.h` and `PinChangeInt.h` libraries to put my Arduino into the sleep mode every 8 seconds and then it wakes up, modifies a counter and it goes to sleep again, but also I need to wake it up when a button is pressed asynchronously.

I´ve reached to wake up the Arduino every 8 seconds using `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF)` and, in other code, I´ve also reached to wake it up while it sleeps indefinitely with `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF)` but I can´t combine that periodical awakening with the asynchronous awakening.

Here is my code:

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Pines declaration

    loopsToSend = setTimeToSend();  //

    //The three async buttons 
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(4, readOpinion,RISING);
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(5, readOpinion,RISING);
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readOpinion,RISING);
}

void loop(){

    if(loops < loopsToSend ){

        byte opinionValue = readOpinion(); //This method must awake the Arduino ASYNC to give a value to the opinionValue var, write the result in the file and go to sleep 

        if(opinionValue != 0){
            Serial.println("Button pressed!");

            //Writing result in a file
            opiniones++;
            delay(500);
        }
        //Go to sleep 8 seconds
        LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
        opinionValue = 0;
    }
    else {
        wdt_disable();

        if(opiniones > 0){
            //Send file using GSM module
        }
        else{
            loops = 0;
        }
    }
    loops++;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Which Arduino is it? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't see `readOpinion` declared anywhere.

Comment: It's an encouraged practice to answer your own question if you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My aim was to attach multiple interrupts to my Arduino but my problem was that I didn´t know if when the board changed to sleep mode using `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF)` then it could be awake using another interrupt instead of the timer.

The `void loop()` method must sleep the board every 8 seconds if no button is pressed. Aside there is a method that is called when a button is pressed, that´s because in the `void setup ()` I´ve attached an interrupt using `PCintPort::attachInterrupt(PIN_NUMBER, METHOD_TO_CALL,MODE);`

---

OP (PinaGamer) posted this answer inside the question, hence the community wiki answer.