Arduino Uno Serial.write() how many bits are actually transmitted at once by UART and effect of baudrate on other interrupts
With Arduino Uno Rev3, I am trying to maintain a delicate timing while handling data transmission. I want to send 6 bytes at a time, which takes around ~44 us when I time Serial.write(). The time it takes from Arduino Serial to computer is irrelevant in my case. I only mind the run time of the function.
My idea is sending not all 6 bytes but a few at a time, so that the total sending time overhead would be distributed between time-sensitive tasks. Note that I will never be exceeding the buffer size, so the Serial.write() will never wait for actually transmission to be completed.
const uint8_t MSG_LEN = 6;
uint8_t snd_buffer[MSG_LEN];
uint32_t us_now = 0L;
uint8_t snd_byte_cnt = MSG_LEN;
uint8_t dummy_var = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  us_now = micros();

  operation_dummy();
  
  com_dummy();

  //the aim is to use no delay functions
}

void com_dummy(){ //ex communication
  if (snd_byte_cnt < MSG_LEN){ //bytes need to be sent
    Serial.write(snd_buffer[snd_byte_cnt]); //send the target byte
    snd_byte_cnt++; //move to the next byte ind
  } //else nothing to be sent
}

void operation_dummy() { //ex operation
  dummy_var++; //do something (time sensitive in reality)
  if (snd_byte_cnt == MSG_LEN){ //if no data pending to be sent
    * (uint32_t *) &snd_buffer[1] = us_now; //modify buffer between 1st and 5th bytes (both inclusive)
    snd_buffer[MSG_LEN - 1] = dummy_var; 
    snd_byte_cnt = 0; //trigger start sending
  } //else wait for next cycle to send
}

My question is, how many bytes should be used with Serial.write() at a time?
I've heard the Serial library processes 16 bits (2 bytes) at a time. What happens if I try to send a single byte? Does it wait a certain time for the second byte and if doesn't arrive then it pushes a single byte? (Edit: this turned out to be a misunderstanding and only the FIFO pointer is 16 bits, not the data to be sent. * Source: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-write-time/233360/23 )*
Would never calling a sleep function and using micros() OR the baudrate affect my time keeping? I think micros() and actually transmission uses interrupts. So different baudrates may delay micros() calls differently since both need to disable interrupts.

Which Arduino board are you using?

the UART transmits one bit at a time ... that's how serial communication works ... the title of your post does not match the rest of the post

Pure USART would send 10bit per byte (8N1) at desired baudrate, however whenever you use USB-To-Serial or CDC (on boards with native USB), it'll be completely dependent on USB

Since you did not say what Arduino you use, at what baudrate, and at what rate you send the 6 bytes, we can only answer generally. Please [edit] your question to add that information. Please add also a reference to the claim of processing two bytes - it is nonsense.

Why did you tag "softwareserial", do you use it?

thanks for the feedback. I've edited the question accordingly.

The Arduino Serial writes one byte at a time. There is a method for
writing a buffer of arbitrary length, but all this method does is
repeatedly call write(uint8_t) for each byte within the
buffer:
size_t Print::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
{
  size_t n = 0;
  while (size--) {
    if (write(*buffer++)) n++;
    else break;
  }
  return n;
}

Notice that there is no waiting between the bytes.
If you do not fill the transmit buffer, this should be very fast: all
write(uint8_t) does is push the byte into a ring buffer. Unless your
timings are at the microseconds level, you can just send the six bytes
at once.

I've heard the Serial library processes 16bits (2bytes) at a time?

Very dubious. Do you have a reference for this statement?

Edit: If you are struggling with microsecond-range timings, you
could send the bytes by directly writing to the UART data register,
instead of relying on the Arduino core library to do so. In order to do
this, you would:

Disable the "USART, Data Register Empty" interrupt, which is the
interrupt used by the Arduino core for sending the bytes to the port.

Before sending a byte, test the "USART, Data Register Empty" flag in
order to know whether the UART is ready to accept a byte for sending.

Write the byte you want to send directly into the UART data register,
thus completely bypassing the TX buffer used by the Arduino core.


By bypassing the ring buffer and associated interrupt, you should be
able to win a few microseconds this way.
Here is a version of your example code using this approach:
const uint8_t MSG_LEN = 6;
uint8_t snd_buffer[MSG_LEN];
uint32_t us_now = 0L;
uint8_t snd_byte_cnt = MSG_LEN;
uint8_t dummy_var = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  UCSR0B &= ~_BV(UDRIE0); //disable "USART, Data Register Empty" interrupt
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  us_now = micros();

  operation_dummy();
  
  com_dummy();

  //the aim is to use no delay functions
}

void com_dummy(){ //ex communication
  if (snd_byte_cnt < MSG_LEN && bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0)){ //bytes need to be sent and can be sent
    UDR0 = snd_buffer[snd_byte_cnt]; //send the target byte
    snd_byte_cnt++; //move to the next byte ind
  } //else nothing to be sent
}

void operation_dummy() { //ex operation
  dummy_var++; //do something (time sensitive in reality)
  if (snd_byte_cnt == MSG_LEN){ //if no data pending to be sent
    * (uint32_t *) &snd_buffer[1] = us_now; //modify buffer between 1st and 5th bytes (both inclusive)
    snd_buffer[MSG_LEN - 1] = dummy_var; 
    snd_byte_cnt = 0; //trigger start sending
  } //else wait for next cycle to send
}


Except for the UNO-R4.  It blocks for the entire length of the serial transmission.

@Delta_G: Wow! That seems silly. Do you have an idea why they would do that?

Maybe it's just a basic implementation without optimizations.

@EdgarBonet, I'm not sure why they did it this way.  I see they were trying to use the FSP UART implementation and I think they just got confused at how to do it.  I've got a PR in to fix it but it has been ignored for a long time.  https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-renesas/pull/304

@Delta_G I wondered why is your code so misaligned at some points in diffs and there is mixture of tabs and spaces... Super anoying as there is always someone with different tabstop :D

Because I don't have the right formatting set up in vs code and couldn't find a style guide or a consistent form to follow.

I lean heavily on autoformat but if I used it then it would make changes in existing lines and mess up the PR.  I'm new to the game there so I didn't know how to handle it.  Maybe someone could format it before it gets merged.

@Delta_G you can set it up by "Insert spaces" in settings. PR will be merged as is, there is nobody who fix that for you.

You are right about 16 bits, apparently I misunderstood this post: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-write-time/233360/23

Ok, I will just leave the serial line as blocking then since I can't get vsc to get the formatting right.  I didn't realize that was more important.  I will just keep the non-blocking version for myself I guess.

I've edited the question to make it clearer.

what a neat hack with bypassing the buffer! thanks.


I want to send 6 bytes at a time, which takes around ~44 us when I time Serial.write().

You are timing the time it takes for Serial.write to put bytes into an internal buffer (which holds 64 bytes), not the time taken to transmit them. You haven't said what baud rate you are using, but I doubt you are transmitting at 1363652 bits per second.
6 bytes in 44 µs is one byte in 7.3333 µs.
Each byte consists of 10 bits (start bit, 8 data bits, stop bit)
Therefore you are talking about 0.7333 µs per bit.
1/7.333e-6 = 1363652 bits per second.

A quick test shows that it does indeed take 48 µs (on my Uno and my IDE) to put 6 bytes into the serial buffer.
Changing the write to write only one byte improves the time taken from 48 µs to 12 µs so that is less time fiddling with copying data into that buffer.
The actual transmission is done by the hardware, and it fires an interrupt when each byte has been sent, and commences sending the next byte. During the sending of the byte your code is free to continue doing its stuff.
There would be some overhead (I'm not sure the exact amount) for each byte to be pulled from the buffer and sent to the hardware.

I've heard the Serial library processes 16 bits (2 bytes) at a time.

That's nonsense. It would help if you specified what Arduino you have, however.

What happens if I try to send a single byte?

A single byte will get put into the buffer, which will take slightly less time, as I explained above.
If timing is very critical I would be tempted to suggest turning interrupts off, but of course then you can't transmit any bytes at all.
This sounds a lot like an XY problem to me. You are getting bogged down on how long it takes to transmit one byte, but haven't explained:

What Arduino you have
What baud rate you are using
What your code is
What is this highly timing-critical thing you are trying to achieve.


As for your question title:

how many bits are actually transmitted at once by UART

One bit would be transmitted "at once" - that's how serial communications work.


Would never calling a sleep function and using micros() OR the baudrate affect my time keeping?

A sleep function? What is the purpose of that here?
Unless you disable interrupts, or take other steps (like cancelling Timer 0) then micros will work as it basically returns the contents of the hardware timer (0) plus an overflow count. It would also be reasonably fast. Running the timer itself will cause the occasional interrupt (about every millisecond).
A different baudrate wouldn't affect timing much, except that the interrupts which occur when the sending buffer empties would happen more or less often.

I think micros() and actually transmission uses interrupts. So different baudrates may delay micros() call differently since both needs to disable interrupts?

micros() doesn't use interrupts directly (except as noted below), however the accumulation of timer overflows is done in an interrupt. Note that micros() briefly turns off interrupts in order to obtain the overflow count without it changing during the few clock cycles that it makes a copy of it.
See hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c for the actual code in micros() and millis().
Note that because of the way Timer 0 is configured, micros() has a resolution of 4µs. In other words, you won't be able to tell the difference between a 2µs and 3µs interval.
In response to a comment, I'll just clarify that turning off interrupts just defers the processing of that interrupt until such time as they are turned on again.

Thanks! I have an Uno (in the title) rev3. My baudrate is 115200 to ensure all OS compatibility.
About my concern of 16 bits being sent, you are right, I confused that Serial FIFO pointer being 16bits as mentioned here https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-write-time/233360/23.
Finally, this is exactly what I wanted to know. I wanted to minimize the time it takes to write to Serial buffer so that I can "thread" without any operation taking more than ~50us. The communication is already very light and not frequent that I can assume Serial write will never block due to being filled fully.

I've edited the question to make my point better.

Regarding the Uno part, I glanced at the tags, where people usually put which Arduino they have. I added the Uno tag for you.

I've responded to your edited points.

I mentioned Running the timer itself will cause the occasional interrupt. I didn't say, or intend to imply, that turning off interrupts would drop an interrupt service, clearly it doesn't. However while interrupts are turned off they will not be serviced. For more information see my page about interrupts.

Also: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/how-do-interrupts-work-on-the-arduino-uno-and-similar-boards/30969#30969

I've added another sentence to cover that. Thanks for the suggestion. :)
